# Angular 2 : Service calls

Tags: angular

I am new to Angular 2 and I am currently working on the HTTP services.

I have a service to create form and an addFormation service.
When I validate a formation in my form, two formations are added (one with my data and another without data).

Below, a simplified code snippets :

**formation.html :**

```
<form [formGroup]="formationForm" (ngSubmit)="saveFormation()" novalidate>
    <input type="text" formControlName="formation">
    <input type="submit" value="Save" [disabled]="formationForm.invalid"/>
</form>
```

**formation.ts :**

```
formationForm: FormGroup;
errorMessage: any;

constructor(
  private _fb: FormBuilder,
  private _formationService: FormationService,
  private _avRoute: ActivatedRoute,
  private _router: Router
) {
  this.createForm();
}

createForm(){
  this.formationForm = this._fb.group({
    formation: ['', Validators.required],
  });
}

ngOnInit() { }

saveFormation(){ 
  this._formationService.saveFormation(this.formationForm.value)
    .subscribe(formation => 
      this._router.navigate(["formations"])
      , error => this.errorMessage = error 
    );
}
```

**formation.service.ts :**

```
baseUrl: string = 'http://localhost:8080/studentApi/formation/'

constructor(private _http : Http) { }

saveFormation(formation: Formation): Observable<Formation>{
  let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
  let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

return this._http.post(
      this.baseUrl + "createFormation.php",
      formation,
      options
    ).map(res => res.json());
}
```

I have seen 2 service calls in my network console : Request Method:OPTIONS & Request Method:POST)

I don't explain this problem, did I do something wrong in my service code ?

Thx for your advices !

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Preflighted_requests

Answer (score 0):

`OPTIONS` requests are necessary to check for CORS issues. (Cross origin resource sharing). A browser is obliged to send a `OPTIONS` request when anything other than `GET` or `POST` gets requested. Or with a `POST` request with certain `mime-types`. This is called a pre-flight request.

It's also used to check from the server side if it needs certain credentials for the request

Comment: hi, I have another question. Would it be these requests that generate me two recordings (2 formations) ?

Comment: no, you will not receive anything from the `OPTIONS` request in your code. Only if it fails, you will see an error in your browser